# Selenium on Mac: Webdrivers do not show window

Tags: macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, macos-monterey

I would like to see the browser window on Mac Os Monterey when using Selenium (the opposite of the headless mode).

Example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.github.com")

input()
print(driver.title)
```

Everything works as expected (including that the title is printed).
However, the browser window does not show up.

What can I do to see the browser window?

Answer (score -1):

It took me a while to see this, but actually the window opens, but it does not show up in the dock or in the Application switcher, so it is very easy for it to go unnoticed. It does however show up in Launchpad (though it seems to behave strangely when trying to switch to it).
Especially if you are working with multiple screens, make sure to "look everywhere".